# How to use memory when calling fork()

Tags: c, fork

I'm learning about the **fork**() function. When I run the following code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int getpid(void);
pid_t fork(void);
int main()
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        sleep(1);//wait for parent process changing pid.
        printf("Child:%d\nAddress:%p\n",pid,&pid);
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Parent:%d\nAddress:%p\n",pid,&pid);
    pid=10;
    exit(0);
}
```

the program always output like this:(the addresses of pid are same.)

```
Parent:31244
Address:0x7ffe5f3cd344
Child:0
Address:0x7ffe5f3cd344
```

If parent and child used the same memory, why did not the pid of child process change to 10 ?  (Ubuntu & gcc 6.2.0)

Thanks for help :)

Comment: Read about virtual memory. And if you are under Linux, note that fork preforms only copy-on-write to the parents memory space.

Comment: Do you mean that the system copies a new memory of data for child, and the virtual memory addresses are same but physics addressre are not?

Comment: Yes ,pretty much. Immediately after forking the (virtual) memory spaces of both processes are identical, with the single exception of the variable that hold the return value of fork itself.

Comment: Thank you for solving it. ^,^